# Time tracker with open API for Mac

Tags: macos, time-management

I am building a local web app with API that will handle some project management tasks, like creating projects, tracking them, sending notification about deadlines and so on. Now I am looking for some desktop time tracking app for Mac that has an open API that lets it send its data to my webapp in real time.

Are there ready-to-use solutions? If not, please advise where I can find some hints how to do it in the easier way because I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there is a ready solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect solution, but you may want to have a look at my app [Timing](https://timingapp.com/):

[image: Timing animated screenshot]

Besides manual time tracking, it also automatically tracks how much time you spend on each app, website and document.

Timing doesn't support "pushing" changes per se, but it has extensive AppleScript and JavaScript support. In particular, I provide some scripts to automatically [export all your projects](https://timingapp.com/help/javascript_projects) and [all your tasks (time entries)](https://timingapp.com/help/javascript_tasks). If you schedule that script to run on a regular basis (e.g. via `launchd`), you should be able to almost-seamlessly push all updates to your webserver.